# Trying to increment an number by 1 but getting 7 instead

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm new to code so the only way I know how to increment is += and ++

Sorry if it's wrong not near PC but will correct it later.

```
public string variable1
public int variable2

if(variable1.Contains ("24:59")
variable2 += 1
```

> 1. This should return 1 but instead returns 7
> 2. variable 1 is a clock script I found witch starts at 0:00 and restarts at 24:59
> 3. variable 2 is for the date when the clock hits 24:59 it should increment by 1, so it should be day 1, day 2, day 3
> 4. my problem appears to be that 24:59 is true long enough to increment the value up to 7 instead of 1

I want this `If` statement to stop once it run its function 1 time

```
public bool testBool = false;  
public int testInt;         
if (testBool == true)         
{             
  testInt++;  
}
```

**My main issue is how to stop an if statement that stays true for longer than expected**

Comment: Read about "edge sensitive" vs "level sensitive" triggers.  To detect the time rollover for a new day, a much more robust design will be to save (remember) the previous value of the clock, and check if the new value is less than the previous value.  That will only be true once per rollover.

Comment: Are you sure the method that runs that code isn't called multiple times? Also, your code has syntax errors and is incomplete. The if statement is surely inside a method, right?

Comment: BTW your clock probably rolls over at 23:59.  Reaching 24:59 would be very unusual and require a 25 hour day.

Comment: This code sound like it's ran inside a loop but i does not need to do such code. You seems to be doing a simple difference knowing how much days happen between value #1 and value #2

Comment: The code is incomplete due to missing the actual time code. I did 24:59 by mistake I ment 23:59. but I was testing it at 1:00 to save time. when it hits 1:00 it is true long enough to increment 7 times, but if I let it continue it will increment from 7 to 13 at 11:00. I'm just looking for a method that will break the if statement so it doesn't increment past 1. but I will add the code later.

Comment: https://unitycodemonkey.com/video.php?v=pbTysQw-WNs I'm trying to add a date counter to this code

Comment: Please add `unity3d` tag if you can. What do you mean that ` from 7 to 13`? Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.   You need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: my main issue is how to stop an if statement that stays true for longer then expected

Comment: i want this if statement to stop once its run its function 1 time                                                  
`public bool testBool = false;
 public int testInt;
        if (testBool == true)
        {
            testInt++;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged with Unity3D I assume this code is running inside an Update() method. What I think is happening is that your code is ran at least 7 times a second (hopefully way more) and for each time this check is true your counter increments once.

There are several ways to solve this. One would be to use the DateTime datatype so you don't need to do any of this in the first place.

The other would be to save the time you check in a _previousTime variable and then see what the difference is between the new time and the old time.

```
private string _lastTime;
private string time;
private string rollOverCounter = 0;
private const string rolloverTime = "23:59"

public void Update(){
    const wasRollingOver = string.Equals("23:59", _lastTime);
    const isRollingOver = string.Equals("23:59", time);

    if(wasRollingOver && !isRollingOver){
        rollOverCounter++;
    }
    _lastTime = time;
}
```

There are more performant and less error prone ways of going about this, but this solution quite readable and answers your question I think.
If you see a performance impact (because you'll be doing this every frame) or you bump into the limitations of represeting time with a string I suggest looking into ways to solve this problem with a more appropriate data type like datetime or an integer with some divisions.

Comment: I probably would have been better off not using my direct problem as the issue and instead asking for a way to stop code from continuing when true in update function, The only method I found to solve this is adding a bool inside the if statement then reseting it in else. but I don't like how messy this can' get.